# How to measure the current delivered to the load by a high voltage (>50 V) non-inverting op amp amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, current-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier

I would like to measure the current delivered to an arbitrary load by a non-inverting op amp amplifier. Key information for this amplifier and design goals:

- The output voltage swing is high (up to about 100 V). The frequency range of the amplifier is DC to 1 MHz or so.
- Output current to be measured is in the range of \$\pm 100\text{ mA}\$ (i.e. relatively low current, and bidirectional). I'd like this measurement to be accurate down to about the \$10 \mu\text{A}\$ range.
- I don't have access to the low side of the load, so I can't just add a low side sense resistor to the load and measure that current.
- The output of the current measurement circuit should be a voltage and it may be low bandwidth (DC to a bandwidth preferably in the 100 kHz range, as is typical for many current shunt monitor ICs, but the bandwidth may be lower if necessary). It does not need to have the bandwidth of the amplifier itself.
- Board space and cost are not a significant limitation. I don't want to have to buy a dozen ICs and spend $100+ for the current measurement circuitry, but I'm willing to spend extra for performance. For example, I'm willing to implement two unidirectional current measurement circuits (one for positive and one for negative current) instead of one bidirectional circuit if necessary.

I've looked through Linear Tech's excellent and quite comprehensive [Current Sense Circuit Collection](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an105fa.pdf) but I didn't see a solution for my problem, which is complicated by the fact that the measurement is neither "high side" nor "low side" (since the voltage at the load varies according to the op amp output).

Ignoring the high output voltage swing requirement, it seems to me that the best way to measure the output current would be to add a sense resistor to the amplifier output and measure it with an instrumentation amplifier. There are two possible locations for the sense resistor, shown as \$R_{\text{sa}}\$ and \$R_{\text{sb}}\$ below<sup>1</sup>:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5ACK5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are given example values to indicate the order of magnitude of their resistances. They need to be high-valued otherwise the current through them will be significant when the output is a high voltage.

The problem with this solution is that I haven't found any instrumentation amplifier ICs capable of a supply voltage as great as the 100 V output swing. I could build an in amp out of op amps that *are* capable of such a high supply voltage (e.g. the [LT6090](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6090)), but I'd lose out on the excellent resistor matching that gives an integrated in amp good CMRR (definitely important for this solution).

**Is there a better solution for measuring the current delivered to the load by a high voltage non-inverting op amp amplifier? Or is there anything I can do to improve the performance in this application of an in amp built out of high voltage op amp ICs?**

---

<sup>1</sup>\$R_{\text{sb}}\$ is the easier solution since the current through it is exactly the same as \$I_{\text{load}}\$. However, in that case the op amp's feedback is not taken from the load itself -- there's a small output voltage error equal to the voltage across \$R_{\text{sb}}\$.

\$R_{\text{sa}}\$ avoids this error but the current through it is \$I_{\text{load}} + I_{\text{f}}\$. Depending on the values of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, \$I_{\text{f}}\$ may need to be subtracted out of the current sensed through \$R_{\text{sa}}\$. This shouldn't be too difficult, as \$I_{\text{f}} \approx V_{\text{in}}/R_{1}\$.

Comment: What is the frequency band of the signal? Down to DC?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, DC to maybe 1 MHz (but the current measurement bandwidth can be 100 kHz or so).

Comment: Is the **ACS709** an option? Of course, there is less resolution... It seems to me a lot easier than using this op amp circuit.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't insert a shunt resistor between the load and ground to do low-side sensing?

Comment: @auoa A lot of its specifications are when the sensed current is > 1 A. I don't think it would give me sufficient resolution when the max sensed current would be 100 mA.

Comment: @ThePhoton In general I don't have access to the low side of the load (e.g. I might be driving an input to an IC).

Comment: Okay next try... What about **LTC6101HV**? according to the datasheet one can use two of them for bidirectional operation.

Comment: @auoa The datasheet says its input common mode range is 1.5V below to 0.5V above the positive supply, so I'd have to connect the output of the op amp to the positive supply of the LTC6101. But then that would limit the negative swing of the op amp to 4V away from the negative supply rail. That's a good suggestion, but it has different limitations than the discrete in amp I thought about.

Comment: I'm curious about your hesitance to build an IN AMP with a high voltage part that doesn't have internal feedback resistors. You can always buy a super-matched resistor network IC after all...

Comment: I see... if you have a sense voltage of 1V @ 100mV, then the sense voltage at 10uA will be 100uV. A CMRR of 120dB would be needed to bring 100V down to 100uV. Yikes...

Comment: @user49628 Yes, I could. It seems like it would be fairly expensive to approach the performance of an in amp IC with a matched resistor network, though. It's a possibility -- I'm just looking for other ideas.

Comment: @Null Did you find any approaches to this challenge other than those documented here? I found this to be an intriguing challenge and would be interested to hear what approach you ended up with...

Comment: @user49628 I'm going to try floating an (integrated) in amp to measure the voltage across the sense resistor. It worked in simulation but I haven't had a chance to test the implementation yet. I'll update this if it works out.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want very high resolution (and, presumably, accuracy), I don't believe any simple op amp will do the trick. Nor, for that matter, will any conventional current sensor IC. You are looking for 10 uA out of 200 mA, or .005%. Alternatively, this is a bit less than 15 bits resolution.

I suggest a rather different approach. Use a sense resistor as you have shown, but use a floated power supply to provide for a 2 MHz, 16-bit A/D converter. Use a high-speed optocoupler to transmit serial data from the ADC, along with a clock and sync channel (so you'll need 3 total). Run the A/D in continuous mode. Use the optocoupler outputs to reconstruct the current.

Go to Mouser and search the optocoupler section by speed, and you'll find a number of 50 MHz optocouplers. Since a 2 MHz sample rate will provide 2 x 16 MHz, or 32 MHz, these optos should do the job just fine.

Make sure you use power supplies rated for 100 volts of isolation.

Comment: I was hoping to use an analog approach but I'll keep this suggestion in mind. +1

Comment: There are also integrated ADCs that wrap this all up in a package - they are marketed as "isolated ADCs".  I think you will have better luck with this approach, although it will be a challenging implementation as well.

Comment: That floated DC power supply might have to be a battery. The power opamp may have difficulty driving the inevitable capacitive reactance (at 2 MHz) of the ( DC supply + ADC + optocoupler).